# If we capitalize each word's first letter in title, is there any mistake?

Tags: word-usage, capitalization

Is there any wrong when we capitalize the first letter of each word in a title including preposition, articles? for example, "Tips To Have A Successful Career".

Answer (score 2):

No it's fine, there are 3 ways to write titles:

The way you mentioned, or to capitalize everything, or less commonly (it was common in French) is to not capitalize conjunctions, I remember this rule to be more enforced in French, I don't know who enforces it nowadays.

Nowadays Many websites only capitalize the first word of the title, it depends on the typography being used. For further reading.

http://grammar.yourdictionary.com/capitalization/rules-for-capitalization-in-titles.html

I prefer the third rule, but as a programmer I don't care, I do what the client or the graphic designer wants.

I think the internet has changed the way we write titles. We used to use capitalization to indicate it's a title. Now we could just wrap the word in an [h1 tag](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_headings.asp)